# How to set a single particular pin as Input or Output in 8051?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 8051

I know if I give `P0 = 0xFE;` it ll make one pin as output and the rest as input.

But what if I want to make just one pin as output or input. Like how we do in PIC Microcontroller:

```
TRISABITS.TRISA0 = 0; // for setting A0 as output
```

Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Pins on the 8051 can't be switched into input or output. There is no direction control. Each pin has a strong driver to GND and a weak driver to VCC. At the rising edge (level change from 0 [GND] to 1 [VCC]) the pin will be driven to VCC a bit stronger for two clock cycles; that is for a better edge.

To use a pin as **input** you have to set it to 1 and leave it there. A driving source outside the 8051 can now drive the pin to GND, giving a 0 when read. If the external source drives the pin to VCC or let it float, the pin will be read as 1.

To use a pin as **output** you'll set it to 0 and 1 as you need. Make sure that the driven load has an impedance high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which compiler you're using. On [Keil C](http://www.keil.com/download/docs/84.asp) you can access the bits just like normal struct fields using the extension for bit-addressable registers

```
P0.1 = 1; // set P0.1 as input
P0.5 = 0; // set P0.5 as output
```

Otherwise set a single bit with bitwise operations

```
char inoutReg = P0;
inoutReg &= ~(1 << n); // clear bit n in P0, i.e. set P0.n as output
inoutReg |= 1 << m;    // set bit m in P0, i.e. set P0.m as input
```

See [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/995714)